# AWS - No space on server

Tags: disk-space, amazon-web-services

I'm having issue with spacing on server. Even after deleting files/folders on server, it's not freeing the space and it shows it is 100% used. Though still space is there on server. I've deleted files using `rm -rf` command. Please check screenshot.

[image]